# Prepared statement with variables in PHP / Laravel - Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the following query (the query is for experimental use).

```
SELECT @sql:=GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(case when alias = ''', alias, ''' then data_varchar end) AS ', alias )) from documents 
left join property_values ON property_values.document_id=documents.id 
left join properties on properties.id = property_values.property_id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ', documents.* from documents left join property_values on property_values.document_id=documents.id left join properties on properties.id = property_values.property_id GROUP BY documents.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I just can't get it to work with PHP / Laravel. I am not sure what to put inside a prepared statement and when to execute what. Tried many thing but most of the time I'm getting the error:

**Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll()**

My code:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT @sql:=GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( \'MAX(case when alias = \'\'\', alias, \'\'\' then data_varchar end) AS \', alias )) from documents 
                        left join property_values ON property_values.document_id=documents.id 
                        left join properties on properties.id = property_values.property_id;'));

DB::select(DB::raw('SET @sql = CONCAT(\'SELECT \', @sql, \', documents.* from documents left join property_values on property_values.document_id=documents.id left join properties on properties.id = property_values.property_id GROUP BY documents.id\');'));


DB::raw('PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;');

$result = DB::select(DB::raw('EXECUTE stmt'));
```

The first 2 queries seem to executed just fine. But on prepare it crashes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case,
not best but better option is to create a database view, from queries where you need for requirement for grouped properties

OR better go with DB::query("full query in single string goes here");